# How to cast std::make_unique so that I can use the functions declared in the class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

Or do I need to cast `std::make_unique` into any forms at all?

I have a FOO class with some functions that I can use:

```
 FOO::FOO(const yoo &yoo, float numbers) :
     num_to_execute(numbers)
 {
 ...
 ...
 }

 void FOO::execute()
 {
    execute(num_to_execute);
 }
```

In another .cpp, my given codes initated foo using the following method:

```
 new_foo = std::make_unique<FOO>(yoo, number);
```

(up until now everything is correct). What I want to do is to call execute on my new_foo. I tried with

```
 new_foo.execute();
```

But it says:

```
  error: 'class std::unique_ptr<WORK::TOBEDONE::FOO>' has no member named 'EXECUTE'
```

`execute` should be able to called on member `<WORK::TOBEDONE::FOO>` but the std::unique_ptr is giving me a hard time to understand what I should do.

Answer (score 3):

`new_foo->execute();`

`unique_ptr` behaves like a regular pointer in that sense, and has a `operator->` and `operator *` overloaded.

you use a regular dot (`.`) to access `unique_ptr` functions (like `std::unique_ptr::get`) while using `->` and `*` to access the pointee.

```
auto str = std::make_unique<std::string>("hello world");
auto i = std::make_unique<int>(5);

str->size();
*i = 4;
str.reset(); //deletes the pointee and make str point to null
i.reset(); //as above
```